# Add-AzVMSshPublicKey to vmConfig fails when calling New-AzVM

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I'm following the [windows quickstart for creating a VM in azure powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/quick-create-powershell)

I'm stuck here:

```
# Configure the SSH key
$sshPublicKey = cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Add-AzVMSshPublicKey `
  -VM $vmconfig `
  -KeyData $sshPublicKey `
  -Path "/home/azureuser/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

First of all I think the following code is wrong, as `cat` returns `System.String[]` and running this verbatim  results in
`Add-AzVMSshPublicKey : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String'`

So... I instead use `Get-Content "./path/to/file" -raw` which just returns a string and the command runs without errors

Now when I run

```
New-AzVM `
  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
  -Location $location -VM $vmConfig
```

I get the following error, meaning the keyData I set earlier wasn't set correctly.
`New-AzVM : The value of parameter linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys.keyData is invalid.`

I've found the issue - So Azure key vault gives me a PEM public key in the form
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBojANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAO...
...
...
...
...0CS94AFAgMBAAE=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Whereas the VM is expecting it in OpenSSH format

ssh-rsa ..........

I've tried to convert it with
ssh-keygen -i -m PKCS8 -f ./key.pem
but nothing gets output

**UPDATE**
Aaaand it's a [powershell issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1400)

Comment: Does your SSH key(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) start with **ssh-rsa**...?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Hi, the key starts with -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the tutorial is a guide to create Linux VM via Azure PowerShell, not Windows. Second, the command `cat` just outputs the content of the file. And command `$sshPublicKey = cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` creates a variable in string:

[image]

The parameter `-KeyData` of the command [`Add-AzVMSshPublicKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/add-azvmsshpublickey?view=azps-5.3.0) also expect a string:

[image]

So there is no problem with the PowerShell command and all the commands work fine on my side. And the error shows the value of the key data is invalid, what you need to do is to make sure if the SSH public key is no problem.

Comment: Hi,
My powershell returns the following 
PS C:\Users\Rowan\Documents\GitHub\CloudScripts> $test = cat .\tempKey.pub
PS C:\Users\Rowan\Documents\GitHub\CloudScripts> $test.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

Comment: @foldone Your SSH public key is not right. You need to delete that file and create a new SSH public key again.

Comment: Hi Charles,
Yeah the public key is in the wrong form - it starts with -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
This is what Get-AzureKeyVaultKey returns though, so I'll have to convert it to ssh-rsa

Comment: @foldone Are you crazy? You got the solution from me, but you do not accept my answer and add another one? You need to accept the answer when it helps you, not add a copy.

Answer (score 0):

To get this key from an Azure Key vault,
`Get-AzKeyVaultKey -OutFile *filename*` returns a public key in [PEM Form](https://www.cryptosys.net/pki/rsakeyformats.html)

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY------
....
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

The vm requires the key data to be a one-liner in OpenSSH format

```
ssh-rsa ....... mykeylabel
```

But Powershell's ssh-keygen, unlike its UNIX counterpart, cannot convert between these formats as it has an [open bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1400)